# HTML/CSS - Wrap text around larger text

Tags: html, css

I have some text and then I have some larger text I want to be able wrap the text around the larger text. Not sure what attribute I would use. 
Heres an eample of what i want but put the image into a block of text:

[image]

Heres my current css:

```
.message h1{
font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
font-size: 76px;
position: absolute;
left: 106px;
top: 120px;
color: white;
float: left;
}
.text p{
opacity: .7;
position: absolute;
font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
font-size: 36px;
left: 108px;
width: 1080px;
height: 421px;
top: 117px;
color: white;
}
```

and my html code:

```
<div class="message">
<h1 align="left">Hello there is<br>Some text here</br></h1></div>
<div class="text">
<p>and Some more text here</p>
</div>
```

so let me summarize what im asking. I have some large text and i want to make the smaller text wrap around the larger text. I've looked around and found you can wrap around pictures but i'm not 100% sure about other text.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what effect you want?

Comment: hey apples, since you are a new user, just wanted to remind you.. to remember to pick an answer that you think helps you the most.. or upvote additional helpful posts.

Comment: @sksallaj the question was fine as it was and was clear enough, Apples wanted to wrap one block of text around another, which is clear enough and easy enough to do. Please be more cautious with your edits so as not to significantly change a quesion. As it is, it appears you altered the question to suite your answer.

Comment: It wasn't apparent to me, and the other two people who downvoted it. When the image was added, then it made sense. Then you'd ask to why the OP is actually doing this. Until you find out the actual reason, answers could be more helpful. The edit was accepted by the original poster, if he or she thought it wouldn't help, then it wouldn't have been accepted. My answer reflects the original post as well as the edit I made. I made the answer AFTER the edit.

Comment: The image shows wrapping around an image that is not rectangular. It you do not mean such wrapping, you should show a screenshot of *normal* wrapping in the HTML/CSS sense. And you should include a jsfiddle for your current code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `float: left` or `float: right`.

http://jsfiddle.net/74Z9d/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. if you float the big text only, the rest of the text will wrap it beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I get this:

[image]

And I believe you want this?

[image]

Then just do this to your HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="message">
<div class="text">
<p>Some more text here
<h1 align="left">Hello there is<br>Some text here</br></h1></div>
and Some more text here</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ah, I see what you're asking now.  I think the others answered your question for you :)

Answer (score 0):

it is really hard to understand what you want based on your explanation, anyhow I just "refactor" you code, probably this is what you want. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LXmR/)

```
 .message {
   background: blue;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
 }

img {
 float: right;
 padding: 10px;
 /*optional*/
 max-width: 40%;
}


 <div class="message">
   <h1>Hello there is Some text here</h1>
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJbY7.jpg">
   <p>and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here and Some more text here </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to wrap text around text not an image thats why I said in my question that instead of image I was using text

Comment: replace the img with another div... set both to width: 50% or whatever you need, and make em float on the left

Answer (score 0):

**Short anwswer:**

I'd just put everything in one div, and put `<br />` tags whereever are appropiate.

**Long answer:**

So first thing, I'd replace the `<h1>` element with a `<span class='larger'><span>`

Let's say you have the following:

```
<div class='message'>
    <span class='larger'>Here is some text</span> followed by smaller text
</div>
```

If you put styles on the `<div class='message'>` class to have smaller text (since it's a container.. or parent of the span class) it has styles of small text by default. Until it hits the `<span class='larger'>` child element of `<div class='message'>` then the text becomes larger and overrides any of the styles.

To have it conform with messages, I'd sprinkly `<br />` wherever appropiate.

Here's a jsfiddle you can demo and view here:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4bHJ/